# WebView2 Control Not in Toolbox

Tags: webview2

The previous question seemed to be about Xmarian which I am not privvy to but I installed the Microsoft.Web.WebView2 Package through NuGet and I have searched my Toolbox in VS 2017 and it is not there. When I visit the NuGet Manage NuGet Packages Window, it says it is installed, but I cannot find the control to use it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the bad post, I was able to find my answer...I did not notice I needed Dot Net Framework 4.6.2 and I was running 4.6.1. Once 4.6.2 was installed, the control became available.